# Using Django's pre_delete signal for new object creation

Tags: django, django-models

When a Tasks instance is deleted i want to create a new Instance of Completed Tasks, which stores the deleted task.
Here is my code -

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, pre_delete
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Tasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TaskName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    DueDate = models.DateField(help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    priority = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.TaskName

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tasks:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    pre_delete.connect(lambda instance,**kwargs:CompletedTasks.obbjects.create(task = instance))


class CompletedTasks(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Tasks, on_delete=None)
```

But , it is not working , instances of CompletedTasks are not being created.

Comment: Have you tried `models.ForeignKey(Tasks, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)` (you'll need to re-run the migrations after making that change).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a foreign key reference to a non existent object, I suggest that you have a field in the `Tasks` model that keeps track of the status of the `Task`.

Something like this:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    STATUSES = (
        ('C','Completed'),
        ('A', 'Active'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    due_date = models.DateField(help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUSES, default='A')
```

Comment: Isn't pre-delete supposed to execute before the object is deleted ?

Comment: It is but the object will be deleted after the signal